# Estimating errors in a least square linear regression

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, linear

Suppose I have a linear model of the form:

$$\mathbb A \mathbf x = \mathbf y$$

where $\mathbf x\in\mathbb R^p$ is a vector of parameters, $\mathbb A\in\mathbb R^{n\times p}$ a known matrix, and $\mathbf y\in\mathbb R^n$ the observed data. I want to solve for $\mathbf x$.

However, $\mathbf y$ is noisy, and for the purposes of this example, I assume that each entry $y_i$ of $\mathbf y$ has a known variance $v_i$. Moreover $n > p$.

Therefore to estimate $\mathbf x$, I follow a least squares regression, and minimize:

$$S = \sum_k \frac{1}{v_k} (y_k - A_{ki}x_i)^2$$

with respect to $\mathbf x$.
Differentiating results in the linear equation $\mathbb V\mathbb{A}^{\top} \mathbf{y}=\mathbb V\mathbb{A}^{\top} \mathbb{A}\mathbf{x}$, or $\mathbf x^* = \mathbb W\mathbf y$ where $\mathbb W=(\mathbb V\mathbb{A}^T \mathbb{A})^{-1} \mathbb V\mathbb{A}^T$, which gives the optimal lest squares estimate. Here $\mathbb V$ is a $n\times n$ diagonal matrix with diagonal entries $1/v_i$.

Now I want to estimate error bars for the parameters $\mathbf x^*$. I reasoned that I can just compute a covariance matrix for the parameters by the formula $\mathrm{cov}\,\mathbf x = \mathbb W\mathrm{cov}\,\mathbf y\mathbb W^T$, where I just take $\mathrm{cov}\,\mathbf y$ as a diagonal matrix with the known variances of the data.

Is this the correct approach here? I know things could depend on the exact distribution of the noise in $\mathbf y$, but in practice this distribution is only roughly estimated. I just want to understand what I could be missing with a simplified approach as this one.

Comment: Hi: that sounds right but you're notation is not standard. If I understand, you are using $x$ for what is usually termed $\beta$ and $A$ for what is usually termed $X$. ( in classical OLS regression ) If you make those changes and check out a text on classical OLS , I think the results are the same as what you obtained. But how you can know the variance of $y$ when you're estimating $\beta$ is a little odd. I can't think of a case where such a scenario could exist  ?

Comment: What is "$\mathbf{p}$"??  BTW, you are formulating a weighted least squares (WLS) regression (but solving it without the weights, which is strangely inappropriate).  WLS is well known, its properties are well established, and you can find formulas for the solution (and, I believe, the covariance) in other threads on this site--and certainly in regression textbooks.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, I wrote that part in a rush. I made some edits. Yes, weighted least squares is what I intend to do.

Comment: @whuber You are totally right. This is completely standard stuff: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weighted_least_squares. Should I delete this question?

Comment: Standard is ok--but it helps to focus your post on aspects that haven't been sufficiently well answered in other questions here.